# clang include multiple search path in the same directory

Tags: include, clang, include-path

According to Clang doc:

> -I < directory >
>      Add the specified directory to the search path for include files.

I wounder if there a way to add multiple search path on the same directory with one -I command, something like this:

```
-I"Dir1/SubDir/SubDir/SubDir/{IncludePath1,IncludePath2,IncludePath3}"
```

My project folder tree (unfortunately) is in a formation that there are 2 main folders for include paths which each one includes many paths for the -I option. This cause the clang command to be very long and i will give an example:

```
clang (...) 
-I"Dir1/SubDir/SubDir/.../SubDir/IncludePath1"
-I"Dir1/SubDir/SubDir/.../SubDir/IncludePath2"
-I"Dir1/SubDir/SubDir/.../SubDir/IncludePath3"
-I"Dir1/SubDir/SubDir/.../SubDir/(And so on...)" 
-I"Dir2/SubDir/SubDir/.../SubDir/IncludePath1"
-I"Dir2/SubDir/SubDir/.../SubDir/IncludePath2"
-I"Dir2/SubDir/SubDir/.../SubDir/IncludePath3"
-I"Dir2/SubDir/SubDir/.../SubDir/(And so on...)"
```

So again i wonder if there a way to tell clang to search with one command multiple search path or maybe make it search within a specific dir

Answer (score 0):

Use options `-isysroot` and `-iwithsysroot`:

```
clang -isysroot"Dir1/SubDir/SubDir/SubDir/" -iwithsysroot"/IncludePath1/" \
  -iwithsysroot"/IncludePath2/" -iwithsysroot"/IncludePath3/"
```

Unfortunately, this solution only works for one main folder and it also makes those include folders *system* ones, i.e., Clang won't show any warnings for them.
Also, `-iwithsysroot` is pretty long, so you may not save much typing there :)
But I'm not aware of any better way to do this directly via Clang options.
Although you could always write a shell script to ease the job...

---

**Note.** While digging through [Clang command line reference](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html) trying to find a better solution, I came across [option `-ivfsoverlay`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html) that seems like it maybe could solve your problem.
I wasn't able to make it work, though, but I still decided to leave it here, maybe it'll be useful for you.